# IIS 6 and incoming page request

Tags: asp.net, iis, security

First let me explain the problem:
I have a little portal that any user from the internet can access.This portal is responsible only for the user authentication against a DB.If user is validated than the portal shows a list of links where they redirect to multiple web sites(this sites are in various coding languages like PHP,ASP.net and Java). If the user input the url off a web site  directly on the browser, the user can access the website.I want the multiple sites can only be viewed if the page request came from the portal and not directly inputed n browser.

I have local server with IIS 6, and the portal and websites are in this server.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.
Gabe

Answer (score 0):

If possible , host those applications as Virtual Directories under your authentication application and restrict access to only authenticated users, this shall solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are able to do this, but you could try this with an ISA/Forefront server.
You can configure this to do the redirecting for you if someone enters the website url. This way users will need to authenticate themselves and you can let ISA or FF handle the authentication part. 
This is implemented a lot for OWA, but can also be used for other purposes (I've done this for several SharePoint solutions).
Of course you do need an extra server, licences and all that stuff.

Don't know how you can pull something like this with only IIS. Perhaps with some IIS Modules, but I haven't got any experience with that kind of stuff, so don't know for sure.